# How to browse items in a datagridview cell of type datagridviewcomboboxcolumn

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I would like to browse the elements of a datagridviewcomboboxcolumn with a foreach and test each time if a value is present in my datagridviewcomboboxcolumn. I just want to know the skeleton of the foreach with item and collection.

I'm stuck with the collection and the item.

```
foreach( var item in collection)
```

Comment: Why would you test (*each time*? What does that mean?) whether the Items collection of a ComboBox contains a value when the only possible way a value got inside the collection is because *your code* put it there? -- To iterate a collection of objects you need to know the `Item` Type and the Type needs to be equatable to determine whether it matches the instance of another; or you need to compare one or more values it contains, inside in the loop. Unless it's a Type which is already equatable (e.g, String). -- Your question needs a lot more context.

Comment: In short I want to write in a cell of a datagridview of type datagridviewcomboboxcolumn